# Autenticação com NodeJs e MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, login

Alguém sabe algum artigo/tutorial/código que ensina a criar um sistema de login com sessão ou cookies usando o Node.Js + MySQL?

Comment: > consulte este artigo acredito que sera bastante proveitoso http://seegatesite.com/tutorial-create-form-login-and-authentication-on-mysql-node-js-express-adminlte-for-beginner/